# Can be the output distribution non-normal using the moment method?

Tags: normal-distribution, uncertainty, error-propagation

I want to study the uncertainty propagation through a nonlinear function $Y = f(X)$. I am assuming that $X$ is normally distributed and I am using the moment method approximating $f(X)$ by its first (or second) order Taylor approximation. By using this method I would obtain the output mean and standard deviation $\mu_Y$ and $\sigma_Y$. My ultimate goal is to compute some confidence bounds.

I know that the success of this study depends on the truncation order of my moment method and the level of uncertainty at the input $X$. Therefore, I am doing a Monte Carlo simulation to compare the output uncertainties. By doing this, I realize that the output $Y$ isn't normally distributed.

So my actual question is: if I know that the output $Y$ won't be normally distributed, is it okay to use $\mu_Y$ and $\sigma_Y$ (from the moment method) to calculate the parameters of a certain (non-normal) distribution and, therefore, compute the confidence bounds. For instance, say that the output distribution follows a [Nakagami distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakagami_distribution). Can I calculate the parameters $m$ and $\Omega$ by using the $\mu_Y$ and $\sigma_Y$ that I obtained from the moment method?

Thank you in advance! :D